# Crystal Reports prompt issue

Tags: asp.net, parameters, crystal-reports, prompt

Visual Studio 10 + crystal reports r13 for VS.

I made a rpt with ***dynamic parameters***, so customers can pick which products to show. 
I tested in an aspx + CR viewer. It loads fine, ask for the parameters as desired and do whatever it has to do. Perfect.

The rpt runs in a custom software (not mine) than picks the rpt's from a folder. Problem: The client program ***ask for type the parameters names, as static ones***.

Currently the reports works, but my client needs to pick up the product names, not to type it. Any idea why can it happens and how to fix it?

Also: It is possible to customize the CR prompt parameter screen (I dont mean make another prompt, i mean the CR prompt parameter screen)?

TIA,

Comment: can  you post some code of how parameters are passed?

Comment: have you checked the database connection on the targer machine?